# Accomplishments installation problem, not showing trophies

Tags: accomplishments

Installed via the PPA.

With 0.1 I would get a force close upon starting the Accomplishments app.

With 0.2 It starts fine, I was prompted to sign into Ubuntu One and the app remains blank. I can't see any of the available trophies (opportunities). If I check "Identification" it states that more information is needed but also states "No extra information is required, most likely trouble with your installation."

I have re-installed a couple times via Synaptic but that didn't help.

I am very eager to have this installed as I am trophy kinda guy but so far it's just not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do not have any accomplishments collections installed. Try installing the two official ones using:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-community-accomplishments ubuntu-desktop-accomplishments`

Afterwards, log out and then back in **or** kill the daemon using `killall -9 twistd` and then restart the Accomplishments Viewer.